# What does this url rewrite mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like:

- if the URL ends in an extension (dot-something)
- that's not ".html"
- don't change it, but stop processing